# how to get data until the next 1 number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a date table where I have assinged business days. I need to get business from, for example, 1-20 before the next number 1. How can I do that? Here is a smaller verion of my table:

```
Date        Day       BusinessDays 
2015-05-01  Friday     1
2015-05-02  Saturday   2
2015-05-03  Sunday     2
2015-05-04  Monday     2
2015-05-05  Tuesday    3
2015-05-06  Wednesday  4
2015-05-07  Thursday   5
2015-05-08  Friday     6
2015-05-09  Saturday   7
2015-05-10  Sunday     7
2015-05-11  Monday     7
2015-05-12  Tuesday    8
2015-05-13  Wednesday  9
2015-05-14  Thursday   10
2015-05-15  Friday     11
2015-05-16  Saturday   12
2015-05-17  Sunday     12
2015-05-18  Monday     12
2015-05-19  Tuesday    13
2015-05-20  Wednesday  14
2015-05-21  Thursday   15
2015-05-22  Friday     16
2015-05-23  Saturday   17
2015-05-24  Sunday     17
2015-05-25  Monday     17
2015-05-26  Tuesday    17
2015-05-27  Wednesday  18
2015-05-28  Thursday   19
2015-05-29  Friday     20
*2015-05-30 Saturday   1
*2015-05-31 Sunday     1
*2015-06-01 Monday     1
*2015-06-02 Tuesday    2
*2015-06-03 Wednesday  3
```

I need to get data from 1 to 20 business days and don't include the numbers that starts again from one (for example exclude rows that have * in front). This needs to be dynamic. Since DayName will change for every number so I can't include that in my where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume that you have a date in mind, so you want everything from that date to the next "1".

```
select t.*
from datetable t
where t.date >= '2015-05-01' and
      t.date < (select min(t2.date)
                from datetable t2
                where t2.date > '2015-05-01' and
                      t2.businessdays = 1
               );
```

Comment: I actually don't. I do want specific month data. but as seen in the table, 1's in the businessDays column, at the bottom of the table is actually June's data. So date here will not work as late May (saturday and sunday) is considered to be business days for the following Monday - in this case its a start of June so that is June data.

Comment: One thing I know for sure that if Saturday and Sunday (DayName column) are the last business days and Monday is a new month business day then Saturday and Sunday will be Business day 1. Also Saturday and Sunday will have 0 Business days left (BusinessDaysRemaining column)